# How to find the Sunday before Thanksgiving in ical RRULE

Tags: icalendar, rrule

I'm having difficulty writing an RRULE for the Sunday before thanksgiving, basically I want

(RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=4TH) - 4 days

Comment: Try other combinations.  Iterate out the days and see if the following give the same days AND whether the main calendar applications support them.  This is old but gives you an idea of combinations https://www.calconnect.org/tests/iCalendar-RRULE-Interop/iCalendar-RRULE-Interop-Matrix.html   I think these might work: RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=3SU or   RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11;BYMONTHDAY=18,19,20,21,22,23,24;BYDAY=SU

See iteration https://imgur.com/a/ZAuIte0

Comment: @anmari You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

(As suggested, upgrading comment to answer)

Another way to approach these is to use other combinations of 'FREQ' and 'BY' that give the same result. Also important to check whether the main calendar applications support your chosen RRULE parameters.

Iterate out the days and check that the following give the same days.

This is old but gives you an idea of combinations calconnect.org/tests/iCalendar-RRULE-Interop/…

These might work:

```
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=3SU
```

or

```
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11;BYMONTHDAY=18,19,20,21,22,23,24;BYDAY=SU
```

EG: See iteration imgur.com/a/ZAuIte0

Comment: The rule `RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=3SU` does not do this. The third Sunday this November is the 15th, but the 4th Thursday is the 26th. The second rule seems correct.